# Why Is My UI Not Showing When I Drop Items Into It From The Editor?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-layout-editor

So I just downloaded Android Studio onto this compute. When the Layout Editor interface loads and I try to drag the XML items onto the screen, they do show up in the constraintView but not in the editor.

I get a render error that states "Couldn't resolve resource @string/helegrtsrewfrtsaw"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="132dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
    android:text="@string/helegrtsrewfrtsaw"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[image: Example Image Here]

Comment: Click on the exclamation mark and it will tells you why :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `ConstraintLayout` as parent layout, you need to to remove `android:layout_width` and `android_layout:height` then define constraints of your `Switch` in the Attributes tab on the right hand side.

It will allow system to arrange your View width/height and position base on parent layout (instead of using specific predefined values).

P.s: If you click on the exclamation mark `!`, it will tell you to add the constraints or the View will jump to position (0,0).

Comment: I tried constraining it and unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: @JacksonEnnis could you please open the Text tab and post the layout xml?

Comment: Sure thing my dude

Comment: @JacksonEnnis You need to remove `android:layout_width` and `android_layout:height`!

Comment: unfortunately not, but oh well